# Make no rule found 'kernel-toolchain' . Stop

Tags: path, makefile, arm, freebsd

I am trying got port FreeBSD on the ARMv8 foundation model. 
I am following the wiki from [1]. But, I am not able to get past the step of building the tool chain.

a) According to step one, I could download all the binutils and it is in my home directory.

b) Next it is asking to change PATH of root Makefile. So I changed it as

```
**export PATH= $PATH:/aarch64-freebsd-sandbox/toolchain/build/aarch64-none-freebsd10/bin/**
```

c) Next, the step is to make kernel toolchain. But when I type

```
**make kernel-toolchain TARGET=arm64**
```

It gives an error saying

```
**make: *** No rule to make target `kernel-toolchain'.  Stop.**
```

I did echo $PATH and found that the path is added correctly.

What might be the problem?

[1] https://wiki.freebsd.org/arm64

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory? Normally building the system is done from `/usr/src`, and the Makefile there _does_ include the `kernel-toolchain` target. (At least on my 10.0-STABLE machine).

Comment: Also, you might have more luck posting questions like these to the [freebsd-arm mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/mailman/listinfo/freebsd-arm).

Comment: @RolandSmith Thank you for the reply. I downloaded the !0.0 STABLE version as well. Could you please elaborate on what steps I should take for make kernel-toolchain to work. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you have to start with a working FreeBSD system. Cross compiling from Linux won't work. If you are on FreeBSD 10, you can use the included `svnlite`, if you are on an earlier version, you need to install the `/usr/ports/devel/subversion` port.

First you need to build the binutils as described on the wiki.

Then you should download the branch that is mentioned on the wiki page. This branch should be installed at `/usr/src` (*make a backup of the contents first* in case you have to rebuil your current system!);

```
# mv /usr/src /usr/orig-src
# mkdir /usr/src
# svnlite co https://svn0.us-west.FreeBSD.org/base/projects/arm64 /usr/src
```

Then edit the `Makefile` in `/usr/src` to contain the path for the special binutils *first*. Otherwise the normal binaries for whatever architecture you're running will be found first, which will not work.

After then you can build the kernel toolchain;

```
# cd /usr/src
# make kernel-toolchain TARGET=arm64
# make _includes TARGET=arm64
```

Then you'll have to build the loader;

```
# make buildenv TARGET=arm64
```

This will open a new shell. From that shell you should run;

```
# make -C lib/libstand obj all
# make -C sys/boot -DWITHOUT_FORTH obj all
```

Don't exit that shell, because there is more. I assume that the kernel build procedure is more or less standard, it is not mentioned on the wiki;

```
# make buildkernel
```

This command needs to run in the shell that was opened by `make buildenv`.

Note: do *not* run `make installkernel`. That would presumably leave your x86 PC with an ARM kernel. :-)

The wiki doesn't mention building a userland, and it only shows the boot process, so I don't know if it even works.

You'll need a Linux box (or VM) to run the ARMv8 emulator. You will have to supply the kernel and boot loader that you built to this emulator, but I don't know how to do that. You definitly need to take that up on the freebsd-arm mailing list!

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the response. I presume that the cross compiling with Linux would not work because the makefile can be executed only using a BSD type make. But Linux has a GNU make. Am I correct?
Now, the ARM foundation model is available for Linux platforms only. SO, I should be able to execute all this in a Linux environment itself. Is there anyway by which I can 'make' the kernel-toolchain from Linux itself?

Comment: It's certainly `make`, but I would guess several other things as well. E.g. on recent FreeBSD releases the `clang` compiler is used, not `gcc`, and it is aliased as `cc`. Header files will be different. `uname` will return a value that the build environment doesn't understand. Utilities like `sed`, `awk` and `grep` take slightly different options. And biggest of all, it is in *not supported in any way*, so if you run into trouble, you're on your own. But what you could do is install FreeBSD in a virtual machine.